# Bedeutung von "vermackt"

Tags: meaning

Ich kann keine Bestimmung für »vermackt« (Partizip II von vermacken?) finden. Ich kann einfach nur vermuten, dass es von »die Macke« kommt.

Meine Lieblingssuchmaschine liefert nur wenige Ergebnisse, also frage ich mich, ob man das Wort nur für besondere Gelegenheiten verwendet.

Comment: Bitte mehr Kontext. Wo hast du das Wort gelesen oder gehört, und in welchem Zusammenhang? Ein Zitat mit ein paar Zusatzinformationen wäre sehr hilfreich. Ich kenne das nämlich gar nicht, und halte es - so wie es dasteht - für eine falsch geschriebene Version von »vermacht«

Comment: Ich habe es erst auf [dieses Forum](https://www.outdoorseiten.net/forum/showthread.php/68417-Welche-Bremse-am-Reiserad?s=4c79f8863f3bb9c896327920247722f0&p=1110248&viewfull=1#post1110248) gelesen.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Vermackt* ist zumindest im Südwesten (Baden, Schwaben) Deutschlands gängig und beschreibt *Gegenstände mit einer oder mehreren Macken, also physischen Beschädigungen*.

> Dann hat der mein Auto mit dem Einkaufswägele vermackt.
>   Das Buch kauf' ich nicht, das ist vermackt. (= der Einband ist beschädigt)

Er wird *nicht* für Personen und ihre Charaktereigenschaften benutzt und auch *nicht* für technische Defekte z.B. ein Auto, dessen Motor mit leichtem Schaden läuft - auch wenn dieser Motor *eine Macke hat*.

Comment: Die "Macke" ist im Schwäbischen Dialekt (wohin ich gemeinsam mit dir die Formulierung verorte) eben "der Kratzer". "'ne Macke haben" im Sinne eines Persönlichkeitsdefekts kennt der SW-deutsche Dialekt mMn nicht, bzw. nur als eingewandertes Wort.

Comment: Mein Beitrag zur regionalen Verbreitung: Im Osten Österreichs völlig unbekannt.

Comment: Noch ein Beitrag zu regionalen Verbreitung: Macke ist bekannt, vermackt oder vermacken habe ich noch nie gehört. (Raum Frankfurt/Main).

Comment: Schließe mich @dirkt an: _Macke_ ja, _vermackt_ und _vermacken_ nein, weder im Rhein-Neckar-Raum noch in Südniedersachsen (und auch sonst war es mir noch nicht untergekommen).

Answer (score -1):

Die Begriffe `vermacken` oder `vermackt` sind mir noch nicht begegnet, offizielle DUDEN-Wörter sind es nicht, also Umgangssprache.

`vermackt` würde dann bedeuten: [besonders viele] Macken haben, entweder im Sinne von Eigenart, Spleen oder im Sinne von Fehler, Schäden, Mängel.